# Keep up to date with Rhythmbox?

Tags: ppa, rhythmbox

Since Banshee is going to be replacing Rhythmbox in 11.04, is there a PPA for Rhythmbox so I can still keep up to date with the newest stable builds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This won't be necessary because although Rhythmbox will no longer be default, the latest stable version will be included in the Software Centre for easily installation and updating.